# How do I convert 2.8x scenes to 2.7x ones?

Tags: versions, conversion, compatibility

I am a researcher that has been coding on Python + Blender 2.78. I downloaded several 2.8x scenes from the web and want to render them with my scripts. I'm getting this error:

```
RuntimeError: Error: File written by newer Blender binary (280.0), expect loss of data!

Error, region type 12 missing in - name:"View3D", id:1
Error, region type 9 missing in - name:"Buttons", id:4
Error, region type 12 missing in - name:"View3D", id:1
Error, region type 12 missing in - name:"View3D", id:1
Error, region type 9 missing in - name:"Buttons", id:4
Error, region type 12 missing in - name:"View3D", id:1
Error, region type 12 missing in - name:"Image", id:6
Error, region type 9 missing in - name:"Buttons", id:4
Error, region type 12 missing in - name:"View3D", id:1
Error, region type 12 missing in - name:"Image", id:6
Error, region type 12 missing in - name:"View3D", id:1
Error, region type 9 missing in - name:"Buttons", id:4
Error, region type 11 missing in - name:"Text", id:9
Error, region type 12 missing in - name:"View3D", id:1
Error, region type 12 missing in - name:"View3D", id:1
Error, region type 9 missing in - name:"Buttons", id:4
Error, region type 9 missing in - name:"Buttons", id:4
Error, region type 12 missing in - name:"View3D", id:1
Error, region type 11 missing in - name:"Text", id:9
Error, region type 12 missing in - name:"Image", id:6
Error, region type 12 missing in - name:"View3D", id:1
Error, region type 12 missing in - name:"Sequencer", id:8
Error, region type 5 missing in - name:"Sequencer", id:8
Error, region type 12 missing in - name:"Sequencer", id:8
Error, region type 5 missing in - name:"Sequencer", id:8
```

I understand there might not be "perfect conversion" that covers everything, but I still hope for automatic conversion that does a reasonable job.

Comment: I guess you can't. The closest thing maybe would be exporting objects from 2.8 scenes into obj or fbx files and importing in 2.7x scene (pretty much what you'd do for any import from other applciations)

Comment: @MrZak that's sad, because obj and fbx won't have the "Blender materials"?

Comment: Yes, they won't. You can append materials with File > Append > blend file > Material. What it can import, it will (or at least should). The rest will be red undefined nodes